# find number of floating point register programmaticaly in c++

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I am working on parallel algorithm optimization (sparse matrix) and working on register blocking. I want to find number and type of registers (specifically floating point registers and then others) available in machine In order to tune my code based on available registers and make it platform independent. Is there any way to do this in c++?

thank you.
mjr

Comment: Not in portable C or C++ - they don't even define what a CPU is, let alone a register. You might find a library or OS-specific calls to get that info, but sounds like you'd be better of producing OS and chip-specific executables.

Comment: @mat what do you mena by portable c or c++? do you know any library?

Comment: C or C++ code that uses only constructs defined in their respective standards and doesn't rely on any implementation-specific tricks.

Comment: Nothing that a config parameter could not fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, compilers do know this sort of stuff (and how to best use it), so I'm slightly surprised that you think that you can outsmart the compiler - unless I have very high domain knowledge, and start writing assembler code, I very rarely outsmart the compiler.

Since writing assembler code is highly unportable, I don't think that counts as a solution for optimising the code using knowledge as to how many registers, etc. It is very difficult to know how the compiler uses registers. If you have `int x = y + z;` as a simple example, how many registers does it take? Depends on the compiler - it could use none, one, two, three, four, five or six, without being below optimal register usage - it all depends on how the compiler decides to deal with things, machine architecture, where/how variables are being stored, etc. The same principle applies to number of floating point registers if we change `int` to `double`. There is no obvious way to tell how many registers are being used in this statement (although I suspect no more than three - however, it could be zero or one, depending on what the compiler decides to do).

It's probably possible to do some clever tricks if you know the processor architecture and how the compiler deals with certain types of code - but that also assumes that the compiler doesn't change its behaviour in the next release.  But if you know what processor architecture it is, then you also know the number of registers of various kinds...

Comment: If I understand you well, because of compiler technique like register renaming or spilling register into stack slot we cant find out how many register will be used for expersion(s). But if we know that our expersions need 7 register or 13 register in normal state on machine with 8  or 16 register dosn't it stop cpu from spilling register and stop slowing down the loop executing the expersion(s).

Comment: The term "register renaming" in my vocabulary is where the processor pyhysically has more registers than it "shows" - e.g. x86 processors officially have 8 registers, but I know some time back there was 32 registers internally in AMD processors. But yes, compiler may use more or less registers than you "expect", and it may use registers more or less cleverly depending on how it decides to deal with a certain expression (e.g. load a value into a register, then do add to a second register, or use an add instruction with indirect memory operand). It may choose differently at different times.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is no easy portable solution.

There are many factors that could influence the optimal block size for a given computer. One way to discover a good configuration is by automatically running a series of benchmarks, and using the results to tune your code at runtime.

Another approach is to automatically tweak the *source code* based on the results of some benchmarks. This is what [Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) (ATLAS) does.